# Powershell script using Excel running slow

Tags: excel, csv, powershell, com, automation

So i have this script that i coded on my laptop that works just fine, the job is to combine two .csv-files into one .xls-file. 
And running the script with two .csv-files containing a couple of thousand rows takes a few seconds max.

But when i try to run it on the server where it should be located, it takes... hours. I haven't done a full run, but writing one line in the .xls-file takes maybe 2-3 seconds.

So what im wondering is what is causing the huge increase in runtime. I'm monitoring the CPU-load while the script is running, and it's at 50-60% load.

The server has loads of Ram, and two CPU-core.
How can i speed this up?

The script looks like this:

```
$path = "C:\test\*"
$path2 = "C:\test"
$date = Get-Date -Format d
$csvs = Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.csv | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 2
$y = $csvs.Count

Write-Host "Detected the following CSV files: ($y)"
foreach ($csv in $csvs) {
    Write-Host " "$csv.Name
}

$outputfilename = "regSCI " + $date
Write-Host Creating: $outputfilename

$excelapp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excelapp.sheetsInNewWorkbook = $csvs.Count
$xlsx = $excelapp.Workbooks.Add()
$sheet = 1
$xlleft = -4131

foreach ($csv in $csvs) {
    $row = 1
    $column = 1
    $worksheet = $xlsx.Worksheets.Item($sheet)
    $worksheet.Name = $csv.Name
    $worksheet.Rows.HorizontalAlignment = $xlleft
    $file = (Get-Content $csv)
    Write-Host Worksheet created: $worksheet.Name

    foreach($line in $file) {
        Write-Host Writing Line
        $linecontents = $line -split ',(?!\s*\w+")'

        foreach($cell in $linecontents) {
            Write-Host Writing Cell
            $cell1 = $cell.Trim('"')
            $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $column) = $cell1
            $column++
        }
        $column = 1
        $row++
        $WorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Autofit() | Out-Null
    }
    $sheet++
    $headerRange = $worksheet.Range("a1", "q1") 
    $headerRange.AutoFilter() | Out-Null 
}

$output = $path2 + "\" + $outputfilename
Write-Host $output
$xlsx.SaveAs($output)
$excelapp.Quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

To speed up your existing code, add these just after creating Excel object:

```
$excelapp.ScreenUpdating = $false
$excelapp.DisplayStatusBar = $false
$excelapp.EnableEvents = $false
$excelapp.Visible = $false
```

And these just before SaveAs:

```
$excelapp.ScreenUpdating = $true
$excelapp.DisplayStatusBar = $true
$excelapp.EnableEvents = $true
```

This causes excel not to render the worksheet in realtime and fire events every time you change the contets. Most probably `DisplayStatusBar` and `ScreenUpdating` doesn't matter if you make an application invisible, but I included it just in case.

Also, you're running `Autofit()` after every line. This certainly doesn't help with performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will definitely try this.
Could you clarify on the `Autofit()`-part, since i've just stolen the excel-code, im not exactly sure what it all does

Comment: @AndersEkelund AutoFit() adjusts column widths to cell contents. If you need it, do it once per sheet, not after inserting every row.